# passing error with socket.io middleware doesnt work but it does work in the general server

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, socket.io

in my server i got my custon error handler , every time i pass him (with next(error)) he takes the error , but when i am using socket.io and trying to pass him an error it doesnt work and i dont know why , can you solve it?

```
io.use((socket, next) => {
const authorizationHeader = socket.handshake.headers?.authorization;
if (!authorizationHeader) {
  next(new CustomError(401, NOT_AUTHORIZED_MESSAGE));
  return;
}
const token = authorizationHeader.split(' ')[1];
const isVerfied = !!decodeLoginCookieToken(token);
if (isVerfied) {
  next();
} else {
  next(new CustomError(401, NOT_AUTHORIZED_MESSAGE));
}
```

});

Comment: Official documentation suggests the following:
io.use((socket, next) => {
  if (isValid(socket.request)) {
    next();
  } else {
    next(new Error("invalid"));
  }
});

Though, I would be interested in looking at the code inside CustomError if you can please share.

Instead of CustomError, try to see if it is working with Error()

Comment: ```class CustomError extends Error {
  status: number;
  message: string;
  constructor(status: number = 500, message: string = 'internal server error') {
    super(message);
    this.status = status;
    this.message = message;
  }
}

export default CustomError;```

Comment: ```export const errorHandler = (
  error: CustomError,
  request: Request,
  response: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  const status = error.status ?? 500;
  const message = error.message ?? 'Internal server error';
  return response.status(status).json({
    message,
  });
};

export default errorHandler;```

Comment: Sorry, did not understand. Can you please try it with just new Error instead of CustomError and see if it works